# Updating a nested Django object where if it the next object doesn't exist create a new one

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, I have two models a Template (QtnTemplate) and a Question (QtnQuestion). The template (QtnTemplate)  has a manyToMany field of questions(qtn_template_questions). What I want to do is when my front end sends a PUT rest command with a template that has another new question added. It will take that data update the template since that new question doesn't exist it will create a new nested question in the backend.

In the Serializer for the template I have the following code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import QtnTemplate
from qtn_question.models import QtnQuestion
from qtn_question.serializers import QtnQuestionSerializer



class QtnTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  #  qtn_template_questions = QtnQuestionSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)
    class Meta:
        model = QtnTemplate
        fields = ('id', 
        'qtn_template_name', 
         'qtn_template_create_date', 
         'qtn_template_question_order', 
         'qtn_template_questions')
        depth = 1

# This is supposed to check to see if a questionId is already set in the underlying template
# if it isn't already set then create a new one
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        questions = self.data['qtn_template_questions']

        for quest in questions:

            questionId = quest.pop('id')
            questString = quest.pop('qtn_question_question_string')

            if questionId is None:
                QtnQuestion.objects.create(qtn_question_question_string=quest.pop('qtn_question_question_string'), 
                                            qtn_question_ui_id=quest.pop('qtn_question_ui_id'),
                                            qtn_question_risk_weight=quest.pop('qtn_question_risk_weight'),
                                            qtn_question_is_selected=quest.pop('qtn_question_is_selected'),
                                            qtn_question_setting=quest.pop('qtn_question_setting'),
                                            qtn_question_answer_type=pop('quest.qtn_question_answer_type'))

        instance.save()
        return instance

    def to_representation(self, value):
        data = super().to_representation(value)
        serializer = QtnQuestionSerializer(value.qtn_template_questions, many=True)
        data['qtn_template_questions'] = serializer.data
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        self.fields['qtn_template_questions'] = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True,
            read_only=False, queryset=QtnQuestion.objects.all())

        return super(QtnTemplateSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

So right now I'm able to pull the data but when I do a post to update the template object and add a question I get the following error:

`{"qtn_template_questions":["Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict."]}`

Can anyone point me in the correct direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with this open source lib: https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested

Answer (score 0):

django [signals][1]

[1]: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/ is what you are looking for.

Comment: I looked at the documentation. So are you saying instead updating using update, to_representation, and to_internal_value in the serializer i instead send off a signal when update is trigger to then update /create the child model? I'm not sure how that would work because in the current state i can't get the updated data in self, instance or validated_data in the update method. So I'd have nothing to pass to a signal anyway.